# Unable to run HelloAndroid tutorial (or any project)

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error

I have a problem where Android projects I create in Eclipse are unable to run/debug.

In the Package Explorer, there is the small red cross in the top Project Folder which signifies an error somewhere, but there are none in the lower level files of the Package Explorer.

When creating the project, an event appears in the Error Log stating: "Failed to load properties file for project 'HelloAndroid'"

I have tried:

- Looking elsewhere in forum at similar issues
- Reinstalling Eclipse, JDK, SDK, ADT
- "Cleaning" the project

The error remains.
What could have caused this problem and what is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to see the `problem`... open the `problem` tab. `Window > Show View > Problems`
paste here, maybe I can help you better with more information

regards

Comment: Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 03/05/11 15:22

Comment: delete `debug.KEYSTORE` in your `.android` folder
locate in `X:/users/<user name>/.android` (assuming you are using win 7 or `Documents and Settings` for Win XP)
after delete it, clean project, it will create new debug.KEYSTORE for you...

Answer (score 0):

Go to “C:\Documents and Settings\.android” OR  “C:\Documents
and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Android” and
delete debug.keystore file. (Linux: $HOME/.android)

Recompile the project and the error should be gone.

Comment: that doesn't wor for me any other advice?